# Hardhat setup deploying a contract

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I am also encountering similar TypeError

```
    Deploying contract...
TypeError: simpleStorage.deployed is not a function
    at main (/home/himdipsinh/folder/hardhat-simple-storage-mt/scripts/deploy.js:11:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Here is my deploy script

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")
    
    // async main
    async function main() {
        const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
            "SimpleStorage",
        )
        console.log("Deploying contract...")
        const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy()
        await simpleStorage.deployed()
        // whats the private key
        // whats the rpc url
        console.log(`Deployed contract to: ${simpleStorage.address}`)
    }
    
    // main
    main()
        .then(() => process.exit(0))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
            process.exit(1)
        })
```

And this is SimpleStorage.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity 0.8.19;
    
    contract SimpleStorage {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
    
        struct People {
            uint256 favoriteNumber;
            string name;
        }
    
        // uint256[] public anArray;
        People[] public people;
    
        mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;
    
        function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
            favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
        }
    
        function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
            return favoriteNumber;
        }
    
        function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
            people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
            nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
        }
    }
```

And package.json

```
{
      "name": "hardhat-simple-storage-mt",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^2.0.0",
        "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.0",
        "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.0",
        "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
        "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify": "^1.0.0",
        "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.4.0",
        "@typechain/hardhat": "^8.0.0",
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "ethers": "^6.4.0",
        "hardhat": "^2.17.1",
        "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
        "prettier": "^3.0.1",
        "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.1.3",
        "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.0",
        "typechain": "^8.1.0"
      }
    }
```

Please help me out with this

I tried the command yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js
and get the error

yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js
yarn run v1.22.19
$ /home/himdipsinh/folder/hardhat-simple-storage-mt/node_modules/.bin/hardhat run scripts/deploy.js
Deploying contract...
TypeError: simpleStorage.deployed is not a function
at main (/home/himdipsinh/folder/hardhat-simple-storage-mt/scripts/deploy.js:33:25)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.

whereas i expected some output like

Deploying contract...
Deployed contract to: "some address here"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In output i want Deployed contract to: "some address" but its showing undefined in place of some address

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using the @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox. In a recent update hardhat team migrated from hardhat-waffle to @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox. So deployed() is no longer in use.

To make your code work replace deployed() with waitForDeployment().

You can refer to this :[MIGRATION](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/migrating-from-hardhat-waffle)

Comment: ok i tried waitForDeployment() and error wasn't there this time but the problem is the output is showing Deployed contract to: undefined ; whereas there should be some address.

Comment: Try this:
 console.log(`Deployed contract to: ${simpleStorage.target}`)

Replace "address" with "target"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @[Deepanshu Chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22302011/deepanshu-chauhan) its working

The updated code is

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const SimpleStorageFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory(
    "SimpleStorage"
  );
  console.log("Deploying contract...");
  const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy();
  await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(`SimpleStorage deployed to ${simpleStorage.target}`);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
```